# Can/Should AsyncTask launch another AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I am interested in caching a lot of images.  They are being displayed in a HorizontalScrollView.  Each image is associated with a url.  on a 2.2 device you simply cannot launch however many AsyncTask as images because after say 10 AsyncTask it WILL crash the application trust me.  So I was thinking about launching one AsyncTask that would progress through each url, get the bitmap and store it in cache.  Since some images might take longer than others I was thinking that an AsyncTask that launch the AsyncTasks to get the image and put it in Cache just be the way to go.  Waiting for each to return is not viable as some might take longer than others. So I think one AsyncTask with doInBackground being slow delay loop that launches off each one.  Is this approach viable for image caching of bitmaps?

Comment: Have you seen the reason for the crash? Is not because you run _say_ 10 `AsyncTask`s, is because you load a bunch of `Bitmap`s and run out of memory... Caching them will only make it worse

Comment: What you should probably do is put the call in the `onPostExecute`, because it will have finished, and you won't have tons of threads running at once

Comment: No there is a restriction on number of concurrent AsyncTasks.  Error is not memory but thread related.

Comment: But what are practical storage limits for bitmaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from docs:

> The AsyncTask class must be loaded on the UI thread. This is done
>   automatically as of JELLY_BEAN.

also since honecomb AsyncTasks are serialized (by default), also its not good idea to do long processing with AsyncTasks and in parallel. If that is what you need look into Executors. Links to proper docs you will find in AsyncTask documentation page.